# How to remove confirm password in magento2?

Tags: php-7, magento2.2.4

**How to remove confirm password field in Change password Section in magento2.2.5**

I have remove confirm password field in edit.phtml

Comment: Please fill password in confirmation password field by jquery

Comment: I need to remove in confirm password in change password in account information tab in frontend

Answer (score 0):

Go to following location and comment the below code

```
<div class="field confirmation required">
            <label for="password-confirmation" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ //echo __('Confirm Password') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ //echo __('Confirm Password') ?>" id="password-confirmation" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, equalTo:'#password'}" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
</div>
```

path : /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

Comment: I need to remove in confirm password in change password in account information tab in frontend

Answer (score 0):

**Step:1**

Comment the below lines on vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/edit.phtml

For this u first u need to override this file

```
 <div class="field confirm password required" data-container="confirm-password">
        <label class="label" for="password-confirmation"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Confirm New Password')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password_confirmation" id="password-confirmation"
                data-input="confirm-password"
                autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Step 2:**

Comment the below lines on vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/EditPost.php 
Here also u need to first override this controller.

```
            $confPass = $this->getRequest()->getPost('password_confirmation');
        if ($newPass != $confPass) {
            throw new InputException(__('Password confirmation doesn\'t match entered password.'));
        }
```

Comment: But after save password it will redirect to login page ??? How to solve this

Comment: @ManoM Its not an issue..its a default behaviour for login with new password

Comment: No, it stay in same page. i checked in magento2?  How to resolve this